# Why is li:active or a:active not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I have 3 items in my nav: Home - About - Contact. The problem is that I want the same background to stay when the link is active, so I do

```
.main-nav li:hover {background: #000;}
.main-nav li:active {background: #000;}
```

(below hover of course), but it´s not working. What can I do?

HTML:

```css
.main-nav li:hover {background: #000;}
.main-nav li:active {background: #000;}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav clearfix">
  <div class="menu-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-9">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-10">
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Maybe `.main-nav li a:active`?

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well please?

Comment: I have tried that, doesn´t work either...

Comment: When you say "active", do you mean if it's the current page in WordPress? If so, you wouldn't use the `:active` pseudoclass - you would have to look at your live source code in-browser and find a class that appears on the `li` when it's the current page. Can you show us actual HTML as rendered by WP, not the PHP template?

Comment: When you create a menu with wordpress, it adds automatically the class .current-menu-item to the current active page, so, you could use this class. ".main-nav li.current-menu-item{background-color: #000;}"

Comment: Yes, got it, thx very much...

Comment: @Pixelmaker, you are welcome! :)